# How to masking DB_PASSWORD field in Rancher GUI?

Tags: rancher

I am new to rancher world. In our development rancher we have developed services and most of them connecting to our mariadb cluster. The password value is in plain text and any one of our developers or any one has access to the Rancher GUI can see the password and other access info:

[image: rancher GUI - API connection to the database]

So how we can masking the password value?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables can be read in a variety of ways. One of which is by executing shell and executing `printenv` command. So trying to obfuscate the password just in the UI is not going to solve your problem. Based on the UI, I could tell you are using a 1.6.x version of Rancher. If you were using a 2.x version, you could have launched the DB in it's own project with no access to the developers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint. You are right. Therefore maybe best to use Secrets: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/secrets/  or what do you think?

Comment: If a user can execute shell into the container, the secret can be read by a simple `cat` command.

Comment: yes that's correct then what you suggest, and how we can implement it in safest way?

Answer (score 1):

What about rancher.server/env/1a****/infra/secrets?
Secrets will be available in /run/secrets/ inside the Container with the given filename.

Comment: I think as you said i can implemnt it as mentioned through this page: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/secrets/